# F# signature file error

Tags: f#, signature-files

I was trying to use a fsi file to allow mutually recursive classes in separate files, but my fsi file did not compile.  Below is a simple example which demonstrates the problem.

File program.fs:

```
module mod1
type first =
    |zero = 0
```

File File1.fs:

```
module mod2
type second =
    |zero2 = 0
```

Compiling with `--sig:signature.fsi` produces:

```
#light

module mod1
type first =
  |  zero  =  0

module mod2
type second =
  |  zero2  =  0
```

Which has an error on the line

```
type second
```

Which is

```
Error   1   Unexpected keyword 'type' in signature file. Expected ':', '=' or other token.
```

Comment: Is there any way to solve this problem without merging two files in one, as I have questioned here ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31086071/forward-type-declaration-with-two-files?noredirect=1#comment50189391_31086071

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd think that this is what signature files are for (like C++ header files), but it's not. At least, that's what I thought at first.

The only way to define mutually recursive types in F# is to put them in the same source file and use the `and` keyword:

```
module mod1_mod2
    type first =
      | zero = 0

    and second =
      | zero2 = 0
```

Comment: So why does the compiler emit a fsi file which does not compile then?

Comment: The main purpose of .fsi files is to define the signature (types and functions) exposed by a module; it's a concept carried over from OCaml. From a .NET interop point of view, marking your types and functions as public/private directly in the source code is more flexible.

Comment: Ah, misread your question. I'm not sure why the compiler emits an .fsi file that contains two modules.