# Forward type declaration with two files

Tags: f#

I have two files.

File 1:

```
namespace A

type A1() = 
   // ....
```

File 2:

```
namespace A

type A2() = 
   // ....
```

I can use A1 and A2 types in File 2, but I can see only A1 in File 1.  I think it is because compiler don't know about A2 when it is parsing File 1.

Is there any way to make something like forward type declaration in this case ? Or to change the order of parsing the source files by compiler.  It will be enough for me to have A1 and A2 in File1, and only A2 in File1.

**Update:**

I believe it is not dublicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866231/f-signature-file-error).  I know about `and` keyword in the type declaration, but I can not merge two different files in one (See question title).

Comment: Quote from the answer: "The only way to define mutually recursive types in F# is to put them in the same source file and use the and keyword:"

Comment: But I don't need a recursive type declaration.  I want to change order of parsing source files.  I need to see A1 and A2 in File1, and only A2 in File2

Comment: Well then you just need to swap the order of the files

Comment: How can I do it in VS? I have tried to move them by mouse, but it is impossible.

Comment: right click on the file and click "move down" or "move up"

Comment: The duplicate is probably this one then:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908473/f-compiler-order-of-source-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> change the order of parsing the source files

This can be done by changing the order of the files in Visual Studio: right-click and `Move Up` respectively `Move Down`

Answer (score 1):

If you have the F# Power Tools installed, Alt-UpArrow and Alt-DownArrow also work, IIRC.